# Can I deploy the python code on my free web space to download web at regular time?

Tags: python, deployment

I have a free web space, I built my WordPress in it.

I want to download some web page into my free web space  at regular time everyday, for example 17 O'clock daily.

How can I deploy it and to make it into a simple web application?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="www.sina.coom.cn"
fh=open("mydata","w")
fh.write(urlopen(url).read())
fh.close()
```

Comment: Have you got access to cron?

Comment: Simply, use `cron` if you can.